# How should I code the Gambler's Problem with Q-learning (without any reinforcement learning packages)?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, coin-flipping, markov-decision-process

I would like to solve the Gambler's problem as an MDP (Markov Decision Process).

Gambler's problem: A gambler has the opportunity to make bets on the outcomes of a sequence of coin flips. If the coin comes up heads, he wins as many dollars as he has staked on that flip; if it is tails, he loses his stake. The game ends when the gambler wins by reaching his goal of κ dollars, or loses by running out of money. On each flip, the gambler must decide how many (integer) dollars to stake. The probability of heads is p and that of tails is 1 − p.

I implemented the modell-free Q-learning method using a totally random base policy. But the code is not working as I hoped and I can't figure out why.
Thank you for any suggestions. :)

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#data
kappa=100 #goal
p=0.25  #probability of the head, winning
eps=0.1 #0.1, 0.005 epsilon
gamma=0.9 #discount factor
alpha=0.1 # 0.1, 1, 10 learning rate
n=1000 #number of training episodes

#Q-learning with totally random base policy
S = [*range(0,kappa+1)] 
A = [*range(0,kappa+1)]

R=np.zeros((kappa+1,kappa+1))
for i in A:
    R[kappa,i]=1

Q=np.zeros((kappa+1,kappa+1))
optimal_policy=np.zeros(kappa+1)

for sa in range(1,kappa):
    i=0
    while i<n:
        s=sa
        while True:
            #choose a random action
            seged=min(s,kappa-s)
            a=np.random.randint(low=1,high=seged+1) #the maximum of my stake is the coins I own
            #take action, observe the state
            rand=random.uniform(0,1)
            if rand < p: #if I win, I got more coins
                s_next = s + a
            else: #if I loose, I loose the stake
                s_next = s - a
                
            Q[s,a]=Q[s,a]+alpha*(R[s_next,a]+(gamma*max(Q[s_next,b] for b in range(0,s_next+1))-Q[s,a]))
            
            if s_next==0:
                break
            if s_next==kappa:
                i=i+1
                break 
            s = s_next
            
for s in range(1,kappa+1):
    optimal_policy[s]=np.argmax(Q[s,])
Q=np.round(Q,2)
print(Q)
print(optimal_policy)

x = np.array(range(0, kappa+1))
y = optimal_policy
plt.xlabel("Amount available (Current State)")
plt.ylabel('Recommended betting amount')
plt.title("Optimal policy: Random base policy (p=" + str(p)+", \u03B1=" + str(alpha)+")")
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Not everyone will know what you mean by "Gambler's Problem", so you should describe it shortly, or link it. (I guess you mean Example 4.3 from the Sutton & Barto "Reinforcement Learning" book.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I'll describe it shortly! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your `while i<n` loop never terminates.

It looks like you accidentally wait until the first win before incrementing `i`. (You forgot to increment `i` when the episode ends with a loss.) To avoid this mistake, I suggest to write that loop as `for i in range(n)` instead of incrementing `i` before each `break`.

This first win never happens, because when starting with 1 dollar, and a win probability of 25%, it is (in practice) impossible to win this game. This also means that your first few iterations (starting with little money) will not learn anything because they never win. The `R[]` is always zero, and there is no signal in the `Q[]` table yet to propagate between states.

What I did to figure this out, was simply to insert some statements like `print('i:', i)` into the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I coded it that way because of what you said that the program never learned in the first few steps and I thought maybe I should only count those iterations when we got the reward. So do you think it would be better if I counted all the iterations?

Comment: Personally I'm not sure why you would loop over the initial states (and why just once) instead of choosing them randomly. It does not matter if you "count" those iterations because you always update `Q[]`. I had played around with that, but the results were just "passable". (It runs slow, Python is not good with this kind of loop. Using random actions doesn't help - a epsilon-greedy policy might work better. Or maybe there is another bug, but I don't see one.)

Comment: Thank you! I changed the loop, counted every iterations, it works much faster and still converges! Thank you :)

Comment: good answer, it it helped you, you should approve @maxy answer